# TypeError: __init__() got an unexpected keyword argument 'rescale'

Tags: python

```
import numpy as np 
import pandas as pd
```

#Imports

```
import os
for dirname, _, filenames in os.walk('/kaggle/input'):
for filename in filenames:
    print(os.path.join(dirname, filename))
    


import csv
 files_ids = []
 prefix = '/kaggle/input/uos-com2028/'
 with open('{}train.txt'.format(prefix)) as file:
reader = csv.reader(file, delimiter=' ')
for row in reader:
    files_ids.append(row)
 files_ids = [[prefix+'train/'+x,y] for (x,y) in files_ids]
  print(files_ids[:10])

 from keras.utils import Sequence
 import numpy as np
 import keras
 import cv2
```

#Image data generator

```
 class ImageDataGenerator(Sequence):
'Generates data for Keras'
def __init__(self, file_ids, batch_size=32):
    self.file_ids = file_ids
    self.batch_size = batch_size
    
def __len__(self):
    return int(np.floor(len(self.file_ids) / self.batch_size))

def read_and_reisze_image(self,image_path):
    im = cv2.imread(image_path)
    im_resized = cv2.resize(im, (32, 32), interpolation=cv2.INTER_LINEAR)
    im_converted = cv2.cvtColor(im_resized, cv2.COLOR_BGR2RGB)
    return im_converted
    
def __getitem__(self, index):
    file_id = self.file_ids[index * self.batch_size:(index + 1) * 
self.batch_size]
    images = [self.read_and_reisze_image(f[0]) for f in file_id]
    labels = [int(f[1]) for f in file_id]
    labels = keras.utils.to_categorical(labels, num_classes=23)
    return np.asarray(images), labels

 training_generator = ImageDataGenerator(files_ids[:])

 training_generator.__getitem__(0)[0].shape

   

 import pandas as pd
    from sklearn.model_selection import train_test_split  
     from sklearn.datasets import load_iris
```

#This is the model

```
model = Sequential()
model.add(Conv2D(80, kernel_size=3, activation="relu",input_shape= 
 (80,80,3)))
model.add(Conv2D(80, kernel_size=3, activation="relu"))
model.add(Conv2D(80, kernel_size=3, activation="relu"))
model.add(MaxPooling2D(pool_size=(3,3)))
model.add(Dropout(0.2))

model.add(Conv2D(64, kernel_size=3, activation="relu"))
model.add(Conv2D(64, kernel_size=3, activation="relu"))
model.add(MaxPooling2D(pool_size=(3,3)))
model.add(Dropout(0.3))

model.add(Conv2D(128, kernel_size=3, activation="relu"))
model.add(MaxPooling2D(pool_size=(3,3)))
model.add(Dropout(0.5))

model.add(Flatten())

model.add(Dense(23, activation="softmax"))
```

#This prints out a summary of my model

```
model.summary()
```

#This compiles my model

```
model.compile(optimizer=keras.optimizers.Adam(),
          loss=keras.losses.CategoricalCrossentropy(from_logits=True),
          metrics=[keras.metrics.CategoricalAccuracy()])
```

#Here I aim to train the model and also get it to run

```
data_gen_train = ImageDataGenerator(rescale=1/255.)

 data_gen_valid = ImageDataGenerator(rescale=1/255.)

 train_generator = data_gen_train.flow_from_directory(train_dir, 
 target_size=(128,128), batch_size=128, class_mode="binary")

 valid_generator = data_gen_valid.flow_from_directory(validation_dir, 
 target_size=(128,128), batch_size=128, class_mode="binary")

  model.fit(train_generator, epochs=50, validation_data=valid_generator)
```

So this is all of my code that I have used. I imported the data using a datagenerator and from that I am now attempting to fit the data via the generator.

So when running model.fit I get the error below:
TypeError: **init**() got an unexpected keyword argument 'rescale'

Comment: What module are you using? Can you paste a [mcve]? And a full traceback

Comment: I am using Kaggle.

Comment: Instead of commenting so many times, Please [edit] your question

Comment: So what details would you like me to share?

Comment: @Aitch All the details that provide a [mcve]. Please read the link.